# css ruling doesn't overriden when using id selector

Tags: css

I have a sidebar on my page that I'm trying to apply some custom CSS to, but for some reason my ruling won't override the old ones even though it's cascaded correctly. Any idea why this is happening?

I am using `normalize.css`, but I don't think that's the problem.

I want to change the margins on `#author-name` and `#author-bio`.

Thanks for the help.

```css
/************************************************
SEARCHBOX
************************************************/
#articles-sidebar {
 margin: 0.5em 0;
 padding: 1em;
}
#articles-sidebar h2, #articles-sidebar p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#articles-sidebar input {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0.5em;
 margin: 0.5em 0;
}
#articles-sidebar input[type="submit"] {
 border: none;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #26A65B;
}



/************************************************
ARTICLES
************************************************/
.article-box {
 padding: 0.5em;
 margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.free {
 background-color: #e3f9ec;
}
.members {
 background-color: #f5e8f4;
}
.article-categories {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.article-category {
 margin-right: 0.5em;
 padding: 0.2em;
 display:inline-block;
 /* TODO FIGURE OUT CATEGORY BACKGROUND COLOR */
 background-color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.article-box h1 {
 margin: 0.5em 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.article-box h3 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.article-box p {
 margin: 0.5em 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.article-box a:link, .article-box a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #26A65B;
}
.article-box a:hover {
 color: #913D88;
}



/************************************************
SINGLE ARTICLE PAGE
************************************************/
#articles-feed button {
 background-color: #913D88;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1em 0; 
}



/************************************************
SINGLE ARTICLE AUTOR
************************************************/
#author-img {
 height: 100px;
 border-radius: 150px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: block;
 margin: 1em 0;
}
#author-name {
 margin: 1em 0;
}

/************************************************
TABLET
************************************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

}



/************************************************
LAPTOP
************************************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
 /* LAYOUT */
 #articles-sidebar, #articles-feed {
  display: inline-block;
 }
 #articles-sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
 }
 #articles-feed {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
 }
}



/************************************************
WIDESCREEN
************************************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

}
```

```html
 <div id="articles-sidebar">
  <h2>Search articles archive:</h2>
  <form id="searchbox" method="post">
   <input name="searchword" type="text" placeholder="author, title, keyword...">
   <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>
  <div id="author">
   <img id="author-img" src="img/authors/Yannick.jpeg">
   <h2 id="author-name">Yannick Šušteršič</h2>
   <p id="author-bio">blablablablablabla bla bla bal.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="articles-feed">
 </div>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
 <script src="js/articles.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the margin is not being applied as expected is because this CSS:

```
#articles-sidebar h2, #articles-sidebar p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

takes precedence over this CSS:

```
#author-name {
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

as it has higher specificity. Check out this [article](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) outlining precedence in CSS.

In order to change the margin of the `#author-name` you may need to use a more specific method such as

```
#articles-sidebar #author-name {
    margin: 1em 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to add to this: if you structure your CSS properly such that you never make overstretching rules, you won't run into these issues. The first rule pointed out by Jackson literally says "all h2 and p that are descendants of #article-sidebar should have no margin, no padding." It mixes both generic tags (h2, p) and semantic-specific ones (#articles-sidebar). It is a better practice to define all your generic CSS (h1-h6, p, ul, ol) in one place - like a UI kit, and then add custom styles for specific elements (#author-name, #whatever-else) on top of it separately.

Answer (score 0):

try using "!important" in the end of rules you are writing, though its not an encouraged technique but it works, or try nesting it from super parents for eg

```
body #articles-sidebar #author #author-name{
   margin: "write your value here";
}
```

Comment: The abuse of !important is one of the worst things you can do in CSS, especially when the issue is clearly fixable with better understanding of css specificity.

Comment: i know that is why i told you to nest better, seems like you have found solution to your problem, good going mate :)